# Haskell. Variable not in scope: howManyTimes :: Integer -> [Integer] -> t

Tags: haskell

I wrote a small code, which counts of characters or a numbers in a list and how many times. for example howManyTimes 3 [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 80, 3] should be 4

This is my code

```
howManyTimes y [] = 0
howManyTimes y xs = howManyIntern y (x:xs) acc 
                        | x == y = howManyIntern y xs (acc + 1)
                        | otherwise = howManyIntern y xs acc
```

And I receive this error message. Variable not in scope: howManyTimes :: Integer -> [Integer] -> t

Can anyone say me a hint?

Comment: The error message you've given comes from failing to load the file that contains your function. There should be a different compilation error that tells the reason why the file couldn't be compiled.

Comment: To improve your question to where someone could help you out, try compiling the file containing your code with `ghc` and copy-paste the command you used and the output it gave here. As 4castle said, there's probably an error there that you're missing.

Comment: I have rewrite my code. I do not receive an error any more but output is 0 <pre> howManyTimes y xs = howManyIntern y xs 0
  where
      howManyIntern y [] acc = 0
      howManyIntern y (x:xs) acc | x == y = howManyIntern y xs (acc + 1)
                              | otherwise =  howManyIntern y xs acc <code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have rewrite my code. I do not receive an error any more but output is 0

```
howManyTimes y xs = howManyIntern y xs 0 
    where howManyIntern y [] acc = 0 
          howManyIntern y (x:xs) acc | x == y = howManyIntern y xs (acc + 1) 
                                     | otherwise = howManyIntern y xs acc
```

The output is 0 from above code in comment since the expression:

```
howManyIntern y [] acc = 0
```

return 0 whenever it finish the counting. It is easy to be fixed by return `acc` instead:

```
howManyIntern y [] acc = acc
```

An alternative way to do that uses existing functions:

```
howManyTimes y xs = length $ filter (==y) xs
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Second solution is very nice and short but for understanding Recursion I think first solution is better.